# Return an instance

Tags: c#, xna

Might look a silly question, but can I return an instance?
Example:

```
public class EcranJeu : AffichageJeu
{

    public EcranJeu(string choixecran)
    {
        if (choixecran == "0")
        {
            KystExtract décor = new KystExtract();
        }
        if (choixecran == "1")
        {
            KystExtraction décor = new KystExtraction();
        }
    }

    public override void  LoadContent()
    {
        décor.LoadContent(content);
    }
}
```

`décor` is said not to exist. How can I pass it to the `LoadContent`, `Update` and `Draw` of all the class?

Comment: You problem is more about C# sharing functionality via a base class or interface. I have added a clearer example below that handles this.

Comment: P.S. As a rule (coding standard), do not use accented characters in variable names in your source code. Many compilers will not handle accented characters at all and it leads to mistakes as the accents are easily overlooked.

Comment: P.P.S. +1 for showing me that C# actually allows accent characters in variable names (*even though you should avoid them*) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer was only partially correct as you found.

**Problem:** You are creating an object of one of two different classes and later want to call a `LoadContent()`, or `Draw()` or `Update()` method on the chosen object.

I have to assume the two classes `KystExtract` and `KystExtraction` have a common base class or share an interface. If not you will need to create/add one (e.g. `KrystBase` or IKryst) that defines the `LoadContent()` method.

The property you store is then of the base class type/interface, so it can hold either a `KystExtract` object or a `KystExtraction` object.

### Your code will look like this (assuming you have no common base class and use an interface):

```
public class EcranJeu : AffichageJeu
{
    private IKystObject décor;  // for example
    public EcranJeu(string choixecran)
    {
        if (choixecran == "0")
        {
            décor = new KystExtract();
        }
        if (choixecran == "1")
        {
            décor = new KystExtraction();
        }
    }

    public override void  LoadContent()
    {
        décor.LoadContent(content);
    }
}

// Common interface for classes requiring shared behavior
public interface IKystObject
{
    public override void LoadContent();
    public override void Update();
    public override void Draw();
}

// Both classes implement your common interface
public class KystExtract : IKrystObject
{
    ... Implementation of LoadContent, Update and Draw
}

// Both classes implement your common interface
public class KystExtraction : IKrystObject
{
    ... Implementation of LoadContent, Update and Draw
}
```

Comment: Finally, i used a Decor class. And KystExtraction and KystExtract are two other classes that inherit from the Décor class.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand it correct you just want to create a instance member in the constructor and access it in LoadContent, Update and Draw?

```
public class EcranJeu : AffichageJeu
{
    private KystExtract décor;
    public EcranJeu(string choixecran)
    {
        if (choixecran == "0")
        {
            décor = new KystExtract();
        }
        if (choixecran == "1")
        {
            décor = new KystExtraction();
        }
    }

    public override void  LoadContent()
    {
        décor.LoadContent(content);
    }
}
```

if you want to access the property from an other instance than create a getter and setter or declare the property public.

```
private KystExtract _décor;
public public string décor
{
    //set the person name
    set { this._décor = value; }
    //get the person name 
    get { return this._décor; }
}
```

Comment: Ok not so much. With this, KystExtraction() cannot convert to KystExtract type. But décor can load well so good answer.